# Google translator for improvement

Tags: pronunciation

I learnt a new word `die Regierung`. I got the pronunciation from `dict.cc`.
But Google translator is not able to understand my pronunciation.

Since I don't have someone who can check with my pronunciation, do I have to
improve till the google translator understands?

Comment: Try https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Regierung

Comment: Speech recognition software will not help you improving your German pronouciation. German speakers have to speak a "Speech recognition slang" to make the computer understand. Imagine trying to speak to your hearing-impaired and slightly senile grandfather. He's still better in understanding than the computer.

Comment: @Janka, I am not sure that this is true anymore. Speech recogntion has improved a lot.

Comment: Speech recognistion is generally grossly overestimated. The hearing-impaired grandfather will always be better at it because he has the ability to **understand**, i.e. to contextualize etc and to make sense of utterances, and to interpolate missing parts based on that.  It is a long way to go until machines will be able to do this. If ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you listen to Deutschlandfunk (DLF) - German public radio. They have excellent pronunciation there, and they have talk segments almost at any time of the day. Is available also via internet, e.g. here http://www.deutschlandradio.de/. You will have "Regierung" mentioned there many times each day.